# why is my minecraft launcher not working?

Tags: minecraft

When I hit the play button, the Exe file just closes and opens again. It only does this after I have installed a mod. The regular one works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run Windows executables on Ubuntu. Download Minecraft for Linux